# Assigning a number to each unique value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm completing some analysis and want to hide some values due to data protection. One column of my dataframe has unique customer account numbers, some are duplicates. Is there a quick and easy way to assign each individual account number to a number?

I've read a few posts on here which says to use  this code :

```
df <- transform(df,id = as.numeric(factor(Acc_No)))
```

But it keeps coming up with invalid syntax?

Any help would be great. I just want to replace each individual account number with a number, the problem is that it's a large dataframe with over 18,000 rows, but some account numbers are duplicates.

Comment: So you are using Pandas? Maybe add that tag.

Comment: Check out [ngroup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html), e.g. `df.groupby("Acc_No").ngroup()`.

Comment: Also, the given code looks like R (despite the original Python tag).